# How to load animated gif from drawable in ImageView using binding adapter?

Tags: android, gif, android-binding-adapter

I want to display an animated file in ImageView. But my gif files animation not working.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this using the latest Glide library. Add the library dependency to your project.

Define binding adapter method as below

```
 @BindingAdapter(value={"imageUrl", "placeholder"}, requireAll=false)
    public static void setImageUrl(ImageView imageView, String url,
            Drawable placeHolder) {
        if (url == null) {
            imageView.setImageDrawable(placeholder);
        } else {
            MyImageLoader.loadInto(imageView, url, placeholder);
        }
    }
```

add the tag in your ImageView as below

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:imageUrl="@{product.imageUrl}"
        app:placeholder="@{@drawable/shadowAvatar}"/>
```

Now rebuild project and run. feel free to comment if any help needed.